# Finding an algorithm that decides given 2 regular expressions $E_1$ and $E_2$ and a non-negative integer $k$, whether $|L(E_1) \backslash L(E_2)| = k$

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

Find an algorithm that decides, given 2 regular expressions $E_1$ and $E_2$ and a non-negative integer $k$, whether $|L(E_1) \backslash L(E_2)| = k$.

I know that regular expressions are closed under set difference so I can find a regular expression equivalent to the one above, and then convert it to a DFA and then break it up into a graph of strongly connected components following which it's possible to solve it using dynamic programming. But is there a way to solve this without converting it to a DFA? (I'm trying to find a solution that's not difficult to implement)

Comment: Generally speaking requirements that say "without the algorithm doing X" are unjudgeable; I might be able to show you an algorithm that does some crazy thing that doesn't look like it is converting to a DFA, but is morally somehow similar (and is very difficult to tell that it is similar).  Instead, I suggest specifying a requirement that pertains to criteria that can be readily measured: e.g., worst-case running time, space complexity, ease of implementation, something else.  What's the motivation for this task?

Comment: Ease of implementation

Comment: Please don't answer in the comments.  Instead, please [edit] the question to revise it so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to a DFA is pretty easy to implement, especially if you use a library with support for manipulating regular expressions and automata.  I doubt you're going to find something simpler to implement.